# Can I transfer a mysql database to another site?

Tags: database, mysql

I've been playing around with WP for about 2 years so I know my way around, but I'm kinda new to working with databases. I've been making sites not relying on a database too much. However, I have a web directory site built on PHPLD which is staring to look outdated so I want to move the site over to a WP directory theme. The database contains over 15000 website directory listings and I have no idea how to make the WP theme reflect these. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can export tables of your database that you want to transfer, and Import to another database, then you should change Prefixes of those .